# Python: transpose and group dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, transpose

I have dataframe: table_revenue

[image]

how can I transpose the dataframe and have grouping by 'stations_id' to see final result as:

[image]

where values of cells is the price, aggregated by exact date (column) for specific 'station_id' (row)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need `pivot_table()`:

```
output = input.pivot_table(index='station_id',columns='endAt',values='price',aggfunc='sum',fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Thank you!! From the first look it works! will investigate new table to be sure.

Comment: Good to know! Let me know if you face any issue!